# Why is there no "archive" site for stack exchange?

Tags: feature-request

I often come up with many questions, and I am not sure where to ask. Why doesn't StackExchange have an "archive" where general questions can be asked and kept, where then users with lots of rep can then migrate it to the appropriate site, (of which the asker might not know it exists) or if not then delete it as off-topic or whatever. Of course not everyone would be able to use it, only members, just like Area51 works.

I could propose the idea on Area51, but there is no category for that

Comment: Such site would be much similar like Yahoo! Answers ...

Comment: I can only imagine the horror show of questions a repository like that would build up as people feel even less constrained to make sure their questions are a good fit for the SE network and instead just start asking whatever question pops into their head and then sit there impatiently waiting for someone to come along and migrate their post.

Comment: So, instead of making the asker put some effort to research/ask if their question is on-topic or not, you put the responsibility to the community instead!? Then there's no point we have help center about the topicness on each site since new users will use this approach instead...

Answer (score 5):

Simply because that has never been the culture here. SE *started* with a laser narrow focus (with SO), *gradually* broadened to the trilogy (in 4 parts) and *eventually* started broadening its scope with SE 1.0 and SE 2.0.

The *implicit* barrier of entry — that folks who cannot be bothered to find the appropriate place quickly find their posts closed — ensures a certain degree of quality control.

It's a *differentiating factor* from say — Quora or Yahoo Answers, which might be a better fit if "I just want to ask a question *somewhere* and people can find it".

In a practical sense, we really don't want people to wander in with no shoes, wearing a Borat style speedo, and wonder why they aren't getting service with a "No Shirt, No Shoes, No Service" sign. Setting up a booth outside for those folks is *not* going to sit well with the sort of clientele we want to attract.

Comment: -1 for the lack of an image of borat wearing his speedo :)

Comment: I didn't want to traumatise myself any more than necessary :p

Answer (score 3):

If I had a question that I wanted to ask on a Stack Exchange site, and I did not know where to ask it, I would first use Google's search engine to put in a few terms along with the term "stack" to see if I got some hits.

If I did, then that is where I would read the Help Center to see if it was on-topic, and if so, then I would ask it.

If not, I might seek a [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) here, but more likely I would conclude that my question might not be on-topic for any Stack Exchange site.

I think asking Stack Exchange to provide a holding area for any question that does not currently appear to fit at any SE site, and then hoping some of our most experienced volunteers, who are already engaged in their own areas of expertise to sort through it, is an idea that will not fly, and is unnecessary.